# What to do if your PC just freezes after few hours of working?

Tags: cpu, bios, power-supply, freeze

I recently bought new processor and after few hours of working my PC just freezed, when I restarted it, it works fine for a while and then freezes again.

Is there anything I have to change in bios (voltage or something like that)?
Or do I have to buy a new power supply? I read posts where people said power supply could be a problem...
I appreciate every help!

this is hardware I use:

motherboard: m2v-mx se

cpu: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%20X2%206000+%20-%20ADX6000IAA6CZ%20(ADX6000CZBOX).html

gpu: nvidia geforce 7300 le (memory: 256MB, DDR2, clocks core: 450 MHz, clocks memory: 600MHz)

psu: ms industrial platinum ms-400atx p4 (230v, 5A, 50/60 hz)

cpu fan: amd avc A113000527

And a picture of the cpufan (I'm not a big expert in hardware)

[image]

Comment: It would help if you supplied some hard specs like the CPU model, the case it's in, the PSU and other components. Going on the scant information you've supplied I'd guess it's down to overheating. What cooling solution are you using? Is it a stick fan supplied with the CPU? Are the vents in your case clear etc?

Comment: @OP: Why do you think it has anything to do with a specific processor-socket?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/701466/sima-lima) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/701661/sima-lima). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

Check the temperature of your CPU maybe you didn't put thermal paste correctly!

Use a program like [CPUFAN](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to know the temperature of your CPU, Then read the CPU datasheet to know if your CPU is overheating or not!